# after download a image ,i want to redirect on another page, but not able to

Tags: java

HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.avajava.com/images/avajavalogo.jpg");
    System.out.println(url.getFile().substring(url.getFile().lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.getFile().length()));
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String  mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=icon" + ".jpg");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",url.getFile().substring(url.getFile().lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.getFile().length()));
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
      while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
```

//    stream.close();
    //   outStream.close();

```
      RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/next.html");

   rd.include(request, response);
```

Comment: What part are you **specifically** having trouble with?

Comment: i am able to download a image, i want after downloading image, my response will redirect to the next.html page, but after download it remain on same page

Comment: Edit your question and add that comment.

Comment: What do you mean by after download? As per this code when you submit from page the servlet return to another page with an image from some url. Do you want to refresh this page again and route to some other page?

Comment: this code downloaded the image ,but after download not redirect to html page .............either i use RequestDispatcher  or Sendredirect

Comment: That is because once you write something to the outputStream you cant redirect.

Comment: yes , but is there any way to redirect to that html page  Syam S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok suppose in your case when the user clicks a link or download button the application should download the image and once that is complete it should navigate to another page. If that is the case the following workaround help.

The reason why your solution didnt work is because you first download the image and write the stream to response objet's output strem. This will commits the stream. So if you try a redirect after writing to a stream you'll get an IllegaStateException. That is what happening in this case and it wont get forwarded.

The workaround i'm proposing is to treat two actions separately. Say i've one servlet which downloads the image and another which navigates to next page. Then you can use jquery's file download plugin to wait for a download to happen and then trigger the navigation flow.

So my first page will be like.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("submit", "form.fileDownloadForm", function(e) {

        $.fileDownload($(this).prop('action'), {
            successCallback : function(url) {
                $('form#nextPage').submit();
            },
            failCallback : function(responseHtml, url) {
                alert('File download failed!!!!');
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    First
    <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img" method="get"
        class="fileDownloadForm" id="imgForm">
        <input type="submit" value="Download Image">
    </form>
    <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/test" method="get"
        id="nextPage"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

So here i have two forms (since i'm using form submit method. You can avoid this if you use links), imgForm and nextPage. So when we click the download button on imgForm the jquery download plugin script get invoked. Notice the e.preventDefault() method. This will prevents the page from submitting so the page will wait for the download to complete and on successful completion it invoked the successCallback method. So in that i use the next submit to navigate to next page. If you dont want a second form you could use another methods like setting window.location =

No for the servelts. I have two servlets one to download the image and second to navigate to next page.

**Image Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ImageServlet
 */
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ImageServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.avajava.com/images/avajavalogo.jpg");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.9.248.37", 18082));
        System.out.println(url.getFile().substring(url.getFile().lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.getFile().length()));
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(proxy);
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String  mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=icon" + ".jpg");
        response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",url.getFile().substring(url.getFile().lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.getFile().length()));
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

**Navigation Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

Hope it is clear.

Please note the two headers in ImageServlet

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=icon" + ".jpg");
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
```

jquery plugin needs these headers to work porperly. You can get more details about jquery download plug in from http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: Syam S  , yes its an good idea, Are you sure your code will work , because i used this one , it still not redirect

Comment: Yes it works fine for me. Did the download happen? Which browser are you using? Just put an alert in successCallback and see if its happening and remember to give the cookie header. If that didn't work could you please share the new class?

Comment: Syam S, thanks, yes it working nicely .but i donot want to use js or jquery.Still is it possible ?

Comment: By completely avoiding JavaScript I don't think it is possible the way you want it. In that case the best thing I could think of is displaying the image in next page and not downloading it. You could read the image byte and store it in a request attribute and redirect to next page. And in that page you the byte stream as an image tag's source as <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,<<the byte data>>" />

Comment: Hi Syam, Do you have any other method without using any third party plugin (like jquery.fileDownload.js)  except javascript and jquery.?

Comment: Method for what? Downloading? Download will happen once you set appropriate headers and write to output stream from servlet, but if you want to do some post actions you need to rely on JavaScript. that file download plugin isn't that complicated. You could easily port that code to your application.