# Wher to keep files to make it accessible in apache tomcat?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a file named **index.jsp** that contains a form, form action is a .java file named **getAttr.java** . Inside **getAttr.java** servlet I am writing code that will download a .jar file located in same directory as **WEB-INF**.

getJar.java code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/jar");
    ServletContext context=getServletContext();
    InputStream inputStream=context.getResourceAsStream("eee.jar");
    int read=0;
    byte bytes[]=new byte[1024];
    OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
    while((read=inputStream.read(bytes))!=-1){
        outputStream.write(bytes,0,read);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("getJar.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    outputStream.close();
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

getJar.jsp code:

```
<!-- necessary html code here  !>
<body>
<%
// contains no code. 
//I don't know what to write here
%>
</body>
<!-- necessary html code here  !>
```

I am coding J2EE in eclipse neon. My directory structure

[image]

**Now my problem is:**
User clicks a button in index.jsp which sends him to **getAttr.java** servlet.
getAttr servlet shows this error:

[image]

perhaps eee.jar is not accessible. Where to keep this .jar file?
**Ask me if more information is needed.**

Comment: Two points: 1) which line is line #65 in your code? 2) you cannot send file content AND forward to next JSP in one `doGet` method.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream(); is the 65 line

Comment: @JozefChocholacek then, how do I implement?

Comment: Oops? Really the `OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();` line? That means you screwed up something **a lot**, because `response` is `null`, which is quite impossible. Check your `doPost` method, how is `doGet` called from there.

Comment: Btw. it is quite a bad practice to call `doGet` from `doPost` (and vice versa) - see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/servlets/2857/introduction-to-servlets/9959/coding-style-and-recommendations#t=201608190635343780117 for details

Comment: And as for "how to download a file and redirect to another page then", see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394538/3511123).

Comment: Now I can download file , but writing different code. I still don't know what's wrong with this code. http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example solved somehow.